# Clean way to disable MooTools in my back-end component or workarounds?

Tags: joomla-3.x, mootools

Apparently I can't have Mootools loaded in my custom back-end component since its colliding and worst even, its manipulating all standard String methods and cause a extreme slow down(crap in String.test patch) and/or crashes all over the place in my Javascript application(ibm-js, modern scripts according to latest stable w3c specs).

So I filtered all Javascript via filtering JFactory::getDocument()->_scripts but it seems to break the admin menu(at least its not working anymore). I also tried every other things found on the internet but with no success.

Does anyone knows the official way to disable MooTools in back-end components whilst not breaking the admin-menu?

If there is no clean way to disable that scripts, what are the alternatives? Currently I see only iFrame as solution (document.write(myHtml)). Or would writing a admin template help you too?

thank you!

(Joomla-3.4.1 with standard plugins like RS-Firewall,...)

**Update**, this seems to kickoff more-tools-core at least:

```
JHTML::_( 'behavior.framework', false );
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
// remove joomla stuff
$doc->_scripts     = null;
$doc->_script      = null;
$doc->_styleSheets = null;
$myComponent->handleRequest();
```

for some reason "more-tools-more" is still on the page.

Comment: Is it only MooTools you're trying to disable?

Comment: yes, at least thats what I hope, apparently other scripts seem to do also bs* with native types, causing performance losts, not sure yet.

Comment: JHtml::_('behavior.framework') : no; actually I don't want to use anything from Joomla. My component has all by self. I guess i will go with a custom admin template in hope I have a 'clean' page.  Thanks!

Comment: https://joomla-extensions.kubik-rubik.de/jcc-js-css-control - the following plugin allows you to disable in the backend any css or js

Answer (score 3):

If you have the following code anywhere in your component, try removing it:

```
JHtml::_('behavior.framework');
```

Else, try using the following which will unset the script from the `<head>`

```
$doc     = JFactory::getDocument(); 
$head    = $doc->getHeadData();
$scripts = $head['scripts'];

unset($scripts['/media/system/js/mootools-core.js']);
unset($scripts['/media/system/js/mootools-more.js']);
$head['scripts'] = $scripts;
$doc->setHeadData( $head );
```

**In regards to your comment:**

I believe Mootools is imported via the core, not the template, so changing your template won't make any difference

Comment: just tried, mootools is still there! Then I tried JFactory::getDocument()->_scripts=array(); which has indeed an impact but it mootools is still there. Also tried combinations of yours with hard reset $head['scripts'] = array() but no, really weird. Is it possible that other plugins can still load mootools ? Because there are many! 'solutions' on the internet, saying more or less the same but never really worked ;-)

Comment: thanks for the loaded by 'core' hint. I am really surprised Joomla loads this sort of crap (String.prototype.test patch, jeez....)

Comment: Yes, other extensions can load MooTools but the `getHeadData` should get catch them whilst Joomla is compiling the `<head>`

Comment: They are in the process of removing Mootools and using jQuery instead. The majority has been done but there are still some bits left ;)

Comment: ok, i will use iframes then, the patches for String are really horrible, in my component, everything slowed down to unusable...its a wonder something works at all ;-) thanks mate!