# Remove joomla inbuilt css and JS Files

Tags: joomla-3.x

Am on Joomla 3.6 series, i am trying to optimize page loading speed, but every page has these JS files and scripts loaded by Joomla 
Is there a way to remove these, dont want to use jchoptimize or any extension, an easy way so that these files should not be there and not delay page loading time

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/media/system/css/modal.css" type="text/css" />
    <script src="/media/jui/js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/media/jui/js/jquery-noconflict.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/media/jui/js/jquery-migrate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/media/jui/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/media/system/js/mootools-core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/media/system/js/core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/media/system/js/mootools-more.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/media/system/js/modal.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {
            SqueezeBox.initialize({});
            SqueezeBox.assign($('a.modal').get(), {
                parse: 'rel'
            });
        });

        window.jModalClose = function () {
            SqueezeBox.close();
        };

        // Add extra modal close functionality for tinyMCE-based editors
        document.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (document.readyState == 'interactive' && typeof tinyMCE != 'undefined' && tinyMCE)
            {
                if (typeof window.jModalClose_no_tinyMCE === 'undefined')
                {   
                    window.jModalClose_no_tinyMCE = typeof(jModalClose) == 'function'  ?  jModalClose  :  false;

                    jModalClose = function () {
                        if (window.jModalClose_no_tinyMCE) window.jModalClose_no_tinyMCE.apply(this, arguments);
                        tinyMCE.activeEditor.windowManager.close();
                    };
                }

                if (typeof window.SqueezeBoxClose_no_tinyMCE === 'undefined')
                {
                    if (typeof(SqueezeBox) == 'undefined')  SqueezeBox = {};
                    window.SqueezeBoxClose_no_tinyMCE = typeof(SqueezeBox.close) == 'function'  ?  SqueezeBox.close  :  false;

                    SqueezeBox.close = function () {
                        if (window.SqueezeBoxClose_no_tinyMCE)  window.SqueezeBoxClose_no_tinyMCE.apply(this, arguments);
                        tinyMCE.activeEditor.windowManager.close();
                    };
                }
            }
        };

    </script>
```

Comment: The answers to https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/97 and https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/4953 and https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/9963 might help

Comment: And you might also like to keep and eye on or help this recent question, https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/26681/jquery-script-loaded-on-every-page, that wants to remove the same inline JQ script.